# How to asssign one random variable to multiple threads in J-Meter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I need a new "ROOMID " every time I run a test. I setup a random variable generator to give me a new ID each time the test is run. However, if I set the number of threads to 5 it gives a different ID for each one. I need it to use the same one for each thread. I only need it different each time I run the test.

I know it is occurring because I am calling the variable listed in the Random Variable Generator. Is there anyway to just get 1 random conference ID for all the threads?

Example

Random Variable Generator creates an ID.

Do an HTTP request and set it to run five threads:

```
1st gets 123456
2nd gets 234567
3rd gets 7451236
4th gets 4452189
5th gets 1254866
```

I need all of them to receive `123456`.

Then the next time I run the test I need them to all get a different ID.

Comment: In the `Test Plan`, create a variable `myID` and in the value `${__Random(1,100,)}`. Set the threads to 5. Execute it. The value of myID is constant across the threads.

Comment: Thank you! I figured this out later in the day

Comment: Can you please accept my answer to maintain the integrity :) Thanks!

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Go to my answer. On the left, there will be a button to accept my answer. Please check this link for the detailed answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Comment: please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the below steps to generate `random number` to be constant across threads.

1. In the `Test Plan`, create a variable `myVar` and set the `value` as `${__Random(1,999999,)}`. You can configure the maximum value in the random function.

[image: Test Plan Config]

2. In `Thread Group` enter the number of threads as `5` as shown below.

[image: Thread Group Config]

3. Execute the script. In `View Results Tree` or `Debug Sampler` you can view the value of `myVar` which is constant across the threads.

[image: Output]

Comment: I will once I am near a computer. I cannot find the be option on my smartphone and I have been out of town for 5 days

Comment: I think I did it. On a smartphone it does not say accept answer that I can find. I tapped the check mark